# Internationalisation - character set to support all languages?

Tags: sql, mysql, internationalization, character-encoding

Regarding MySql, is there a character set to support all or the vast majority of languages?

Comment: Just a heads up, the real trick isn't encoding all the Unicode characters. It is finding a font in your UI that can display a wide-enough range of them for your particular application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unicode.  It has several encodings: UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

UTF-8 (8-bit UCS/Unicode Transformation Format) is a variable-length character encoding for Unicode. It is able to represent any character in the Unicode standard, yet is backwards compatible with ASCII.

Comment: Yes. It's optimized for Western European languages/ASCII compatibility but can represent any valid Unicode character.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, UTF-8. Go read [Joel's blog post about Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and you'll understand why.

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 should be your first choice.

Comment: UTF-8 is an *encoding*, not a character set. Unicode is the character set.

Comment: Sure enough, but then again, “character set” is often used mistakenly instead of “encoding”.  See what it's called in HTTP!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't know there's a difference because the terms are usually used synonymously but it seems this is because most people don't know the difference. ;-) Sorry.